# Jupyter notebook can't execute (Windows Power) shell commands: "The system cannot find the path specified."

Tags: python, powershell, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, path

I am writing some code in a Jupyter Notebook in Visual Studio Code on Windows. Sometimes when I need a package, I just install it from the notebook with `!pip install package`. All worked good as allways, but suddenly, without apparent reason to it, everything stopped working completely. When I now run this command, Visual Studio Code prompts two lines stating:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I've tried everything in my power and am desperate for advise. I have re-installed VSC, I have re-installed python 3.11, then I newly installed python 3.12 instead. I've been digging on the error specifically but can't find much. I do see however that even `!pwd` printing the working directory returns the same error, so the exclamation mark, or the connection from the notebook to the windows powershell is not working. I've checked the windows powershell path, and all relevant things such as python, pip and so on should be in there:

```
PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\etc\> $env:PATH -split ';'
C:\WINDOWS\system32
C:\WINDOWS
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\
C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\
C:\Users\ms\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\
C:\Users\ms\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\
C:\Users\ms\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\
C:\Users\ms\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
C:\Users\ms\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
```

I am not sure, but I think Ipython package is responsible, If I check if this package is available it prints:

```
import IPython
print(IPython.__version__)
8.21.0
```

Why is this happening? What can I still do to fix my notebook environment to run shell commands ?

```
get_ipython().__class__.__name__
'ZMQInteractiveShell'
```

Comment: The error message "The system cannot find the path specified" might indicate 
that the path of the Python interpreter is not correctly set. Could you please check your python interpreter?